# Label and input elements are not on the same row

Tags: html, css

How can I do it so that the `label` and `input` *elements* are placed on the same *row*? Can anyone help me with this?

```css
.entry:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.glyphicon {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="control-group" id="fields">
      <label class="control-label" for="field1">Nice Multiple Form Fields</label>
      <div class="controls"> 
        <form role="form" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="entry input-group col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" placeholder="Type something">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The for attribute of the  tag should be equal to the id attribute of the related element to bind them together, however you don't have id in your input div..

try add this :

```
<input class="form-control" id="field1" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place the `label` above the `input` *element* since both are *inline* *elements* by default:

```css
.entry:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.glyphicon {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="control-group" id="fields">
      <div class="controls"> 
        <form role="form" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="entry input-group col-xs-3">
            <label class="control-label" for="field1">Nice Multiple Form Fields</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```